# How to exclude between times in T-Sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I got below table, I want to exclude between times?

```
declare @t table (id int, name varchar(50), starttime time(3),endtime time(3))
insert into @t
        ( id, name, starttime, endtime )
values ( 1,'Steve','00:00:00.000','23:59:59.999')
,( 2,'Steve','03:00:00.000','04:00:00.000')
,( 3,'Steve','00:00:00.000','23:59:59.999')
,( 4,'Steve','09:30:00.000','11:30:00.000')
```

if current time is `'03:10:00.000'` then I want exclude between time,

```
1,'Steve','00:00:00.000','23:59:59.999'
3,'Steve','00:00:00.000','23:59:59.999'
4,'Steve','09:30:00.000','11:30:00.000'
```

any help? Thanks

Comment: why you did't exclude 1,'Steve','00:00:00.000','23:59:59.999'?

Comment: @xLiSPirit, I may asked wrong. but I want to select data from  '00:00:00.000' to starttime and again from endtime to '23:59:59.999'. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (assumed you have a time-variable named `currenttime`):

```
SELECT id, name, starttime, endtime
FROM @t
WHERE starttime > currenttime OR endtime < currentTime
```

Comment: It is selecting between time, I want to exclude? Thanks